# How to enable gzip compression in tomcat server 9?

Tags: tomcat9

I have added above changes in my server.xml file of tomcat and when i get response from service running in same tomcat server its response body size is not decreasing.

I am also using postman to invoke my service APIs.

May be the checks i am doing are wrong anyone can help with this how to verify the compression is working or not? I have noted that in header "Content-Encoding":gzip is present.

I have also tried all possible compressibleMimeType="application/json" still I am not able to see the compression of response.